# Monitor a multiprocessing.pool.Pool object from an async function

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing

I have a `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` that is managed by a discord bot. Since discord.py is async, i use `pool.starmap_async()`, `pool.apply_async()` and `AsyncResult.get()` to manage tasks. the bot starts ONE pool on startup (it may seem weird but it is the most efficient approach for what i'm doing due to long init times)

is there a way i can check on how many processes are currently queued/executing in the pool at any given moment? the checking function would have access to the `Pool` itself but not to any `AsyncResult`s.

i'm also open to other approaches that yeild the same result, the # of active/queued processes in the pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since discord.py is async, i use `pool.starmap_async()`, `pool.apply_async()` and `AsyncResult.get()` to manage tasks.

Unless you take special precautions, this does not look correct because `AsyncResult.get()` will block the event loop. The *async* in the name of methods like `apply_async` is not the kind of async deployed by asyncio. Multiprocessing uses sync code to communicate with the subprocesses, doing so in background threads to allow your code to proceed with other things.

A safer way to combine asyncio and multiprocessing is the [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) module which provides the [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) class that uses multiprocessing internally, and whose executors asyncio supports via [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor).

> is there a way i can check on how many processes are currently queued/executing in the pool at any given moment?

I don't think there is public API to query that information, but if you own the pool, you can easily maintain the necessary stats. For example (untested):

```
class Pool:
    def __init__(self, nworkers):
        self._executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(nworkers)
        self._nworkers = nworkers
        self._submitted = 0

    async def submit(self, fn, *args):
        self._submitted += 1
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        fut = loop.run_in_executor(self._executor, fn, *args)
        try:
            return await fut
        finally:
            self._submitted -= 1

    def stats(self):
        queued = max(0, self._submitted - self._nworkers)
        executing = min(self._submitted, self._nworkers)
        return queued, executing
```

You would use it by calling `submit()`, which you can either await to get the result immediately, or pass to `create_task()` to get a future which you can await later or `gather()` along with other futures, etc.

Comment: I realized early on that result.get() blocks everything so that gets run in the asyncio excecutor. Though, I’ll give your suggestions a try. Thanks!

Comment: @melody_florum Sure, that works too, and you could adapt my stats class to that approach just fine. Using `ProcessPoolExecutor` directly from asyncio feels a bit cleaner because otherwise you are using a threaded executor to access the result of the process executor - more latency, more complexity and more chance of some interaction between the components going wrong.